# Selenium click doesn't wait webpage load in firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

When I try to use the selenium click in firefox, it doesn't wait till the element load completes.

Has anybody faced a similar problem?

Comment: Yes.  Probably running java.  Usually to wait I have to check in loop that a tag is not null the java is updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should define default timeout of `Webdriver` after initialization as following :

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

After that you can wait that web element before clicking it like following :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By locator));
```